# Trick to expand Xamarin Form WebView as per dynamic content

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a WebView in my project. It can have dynamic html content. For now i have given fixed width and height to WebView and it scrolls. But i want to remove scroll by increasing height of WebView dynamically.

Is there any way like by creating custom renderer or something?

Sample code

```
var webvw = new Webview();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
                "@font-face {" +
                "font-family: Roboto-Medium;" + fntsrc + "}" +
                "html,body{margin:0px;}" +
                "body {" +
                "font-family: Roboto-Medium;" +
                "font-size: 12px" + 
                "text-align: left;" +
                "color: #acacac;" + "}" +
                "body :first-child{" +
                "font-family: Roboto-Medium;" +
                "font-size: 12px" + 
                "font-weight: 300;" +
                "line-height: 24px;" +
                "text-align: left;" +
                "color: #ffffff;" + "}" +
                "</style>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body style=\"background-color: transparent;\" >" +
                dynamicContent + "</body>" + "</html>";
                webvw.Source = htmlSource;
                webvw.WidthRequest = 500;
                webvw.HeightRequest = 500;

SatackLayout webContnet=new StackLayout{
   VerticalOptions=LayoutOption.FillAndExpand,
   Orientation=StackOrientation.Vertical
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way but it is complicated. The WebView won't automatically size to its content, so the only way you could do it is if the content notifies your code how big it is.

To do this you will need to [Invoke C# from Javascript](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/#Invoking_C_from_JavaScript).

Its a mildly complex procedure and you will need a CustomRenderer and also setup properties in each of the native projects. Follow the link above for a step by step guide on how to do it.

The Javascript you invoke something like this to get the height

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

Then when its returned back, set your WebView to that height. You may also need to wait until the NavigationCompleted Event is raised before doing this to ensure the contents have loaded in your WebView.

Comment: @Atul any chance you can provide details?

Comment: This worked for me, much prefer this route rather than going the Custom Renderer route

Answer (score 3):

ok here is my "*if it looks stupid but works it ain't stupid*"-answer.

i run into the same problem and searched for a way to get the possible height.

my solutions is now to create a lable with costum renderes to convert the html code. the label has a property for height and width ;)

so i create the label, put it in a StackLayout(it needs to be rendered), get the size to the WebView, remove the label from the StackLayout and add now the WebView with a perfect size :)

```
webView = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = htmlCode;
webView.Source = htmlSource;

tmpLable = new HyperLinkLabel {
    Text = htmlCode,
};

stackLayout.Children.Add(tmpLable);

webView.WidthRequest = tmpLable.Width;
webView.HeightRequest = tmpLable.Height;

stackLayout.Children.Remove(text);

stackLayout.Children.Add(web);
```

Comment: Labels with TextType = HTML and WebView render things differently. It will be similar for regular text, but for more complicated HTML the sizes won't match. For example, I don't think the label renders new line characters.